# Integrate $\int_0^T \frac{e^s (1+\beta e^{\theta s})}{\sqrt{1+e^s (1+\beta e^{\theta s})} }\, ds$

Tags: calculus, integration

> Integrate $$\int_0^T \frac{e^s (1+\beta e^{\theta s})}{\sqrt{1+e^s (1+\beta e^{\theta s})} }\, ds$$

I have tried integration by parts and change of variable but I'm not able to solve thus far.

From comments:

> the integral comes up when performing a deterministic time-transform to a process with stationary and independent increments
>
> I tried integration by parts noticing that if
> $g(s) = \sqrt{1+e^s(1+\beta e^{\theta s})}$

Comment: On this site, posts that merely state a problem with no context are discouraged. You can edit the post to improve it by explaining where you encountered the integral, why it is of interest, and what you have already attempted.

Comment: $\theta$ is a positive parameter between 0 and 1

Comment: the integral comes up when performing a deterministic time-transform to a process with stationary and independent increments

Comment: What is $\beta$?

Comment: $\beta$ is a constant

Comment: if $g(s) = \sqrt{1+e^s (1+\beta e^{\theta s})}$ and $f(s) = e^s (1+\beta e^{\theta s})$, then

$g'(s) = \frac{f'(s)}{2 g(s)}$